# Set kernel parameter for cgroup_enable=memory

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, redhat, cgroups, datadog

I am on a RHEL system and I would like to add the following parameters so that I can have my datadog + docker integration as described here (https://github.com/DataDog/docker-dd-agent#cgroups). I need to set the following kernel parameters:

`cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1`

I was planning to use something like:

`cgset -r cgroup_memory=enable`

but I get the error `wrong -r  parameter (cgroup_enable=memory)`

Comment: They are kernel boot options, normally configured in [grub](http://www.unixarena.com/2015/04/how-to-edit-the-grub-on-rhel-7.html).
 [Unix & Linux stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com) might help.

Comment: @Matt aren't the settings I mentioned above already enabled by default on RHEL systems?